# Covert spark dataframe to Scala Map collection

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the dataframe like below.

```
scala> df.show
+---+-------+
|key|  count|
+---+-------+
| 11| 100212|
| 12| 122371|
| 13| 235637|
| 14|  54923|
| 15|   9785|
| 16|   5217|
+---+-------+
```

I am looking at the ways to convert it into a Map like below. Please help.

```
Map(
"11" -> "100212",
"12" -> "122371",
"13" -> "235637",
"14" -> "54923",
"15" -> "9785",
"16" -> "9785"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.collect().map(row => row.getAs[String](0) -> row.getAs[String](1)).toMap
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`collectAsMap`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.html#collectAsMap():scala.collection.Map%5BK,V%5D) method.

```
val result = data.as[(String, String)].rdd.collectAsMap()
// result: Map[String, String] = Map(12 -> 122371, 15 -> 9785, 11 -> 100212, 14 -> 54923, 16 -> 5217, 13 -> 235637)
```

---

BTW, remember that collecting all the data to the driver is an expensive operation and may result in out of memory errors, make sure the data is small before.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` function to convert columns of type `map` & collect data. Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+---+------+
|key|value |
+---+------+
|11 |100212|
|12 |122371|
|13 |235637|
|14 |54923 |
|15 |9785  |
|16 |5217  |
+---+------+


scala> df
.select(map(df.columns.map(col):_*).as("map"))
.as[Map[String,String]]
.collect()
.reduce(_ ++ _)

res48: Map[String,String] = Map(12 -> 122371, 15 -> 9785, 11 -> 100212, 13 -> 235637, 16 -> 5217, 14 -> 54923)
```